# Typo3: Create subpage under the root page and it's says Page not found. What is missing?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

1. I created Root page as a Home and it's displaying content.
2. When I create subpage with locations it's says not found. Find below screenshot.

**Front page**

[image]

**Home Page (Working)**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the required .htaccess which should be created during installation (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/In-depth/SystemRequirements/Index.html#apache).

Save this default configuration https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/9.5/typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess to your `<document root>/.htaccess`.

Comment: The main root page is working and showing all content. I have same .htaccess file.

Comment: The root page is always working, even without or malfunctioning .htaccess file. Please make sure that the file is located in your dorcument root and that the Apache Module mod_rewrite is enabled in your hosting environment.

Comment: Yes, mod_rewrite module is enabled and the file is also in the root path.

Comment: Mind that it is not the root path of the typo3 installation but the web root. That is where the index.php is. By default `public/.htaccess`, but could be also `web/.htaccess`.  Also check if .htaccess is allowed to be executed (`AllowOverride All`). For example, put some gibberish in it and confirm that this produces an error.

Comment: We should under (nearly) no circumstances see the default Apache 404 page in a properly set up TYPO3.